# PIDPressure In DO

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have a 3 nodes-cluster on Digital Ocean, I have around 22 pods, most of them are golang microservices with a few open sources, my pods are getting evicted and I cannot seem to debug that PIDPressure issue. Can anyone suggest where should I start for the debugging.